# How to pass empty argument to Popen (with shell=False)?

Tags: python

I have external script (sh), i would like to do something like this:

```
arg1 = 'some string'
arg2 = 'some string2'
arg3 = ''

cmd = ['/usr/local/bin/myscript', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

I seems, that if "arg3" is empty, my script i called only with two arguments,
how can I pass "arg3" event if it's empty?

Comment: how's that supposed to work from command line?

Comment: sh test.sh 123 345 "" - you can check number of args in script by "echo $#"

Comment: so, why your `arg3` is not `'""'` ?

Comment: Yeah, it works, but is there any better way than checking and escaping any empty string?

Comment: @Maciej Kucharz: If passing `'""'` does work (which is wrong BTW), but `''` does not, then your problem is probably in the script you call. If that is a shell script, you may have forgotten to quote the arguments. Besides that, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I seems that it works without any modifications. I had bug in my test script :( should I delete question? Anyway @unutbu response with "shlex" example is nice..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

test.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

test2.py:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd="test.py 'some string' 'some string2' '' "
proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Running test2.py yields

```
['test.py', 'some string', 'some string2', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Popen(cmd[0] + [ repr(x) for x in cmd[1:]], 
shell=False, 
stdin=PIPE, 
stdout=PIPE, 
stderr=PIPE)
```

Comment: repr() works fine, for arguments, but there is a problem with first element which is a path to script

Answer (score 0):

Mayby `arg3 = '""'` ?